# How to make this program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm try to make this: your enter a word like this: *Happy* and than the program returns somethings like : *yppaH* or *appHy*.

The problem is that I get just one letter : *y* or *H*, etc..

```
import random
def myfunction():
    """change letter's position"""
    words = input("writte one word of your choice? : ")
    words = random.choice(words)
    print('E-G says : '+ words)
```

Comment: Do you want the word to be just reversed?

Comment: random.choice() picks one letter. You might reverse the word or do the other transformation you mentioned Happy to appHy, store these in a say list, than use random.choice on that list. Voila.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `sample`, not `choice`.

```
import random
# it is better to have imports at the beginning of your file
def myfunction():
    """change letter's position"""
    word = input("writte one word of your choice? : ")
    new_letters = random.sample(word, len(word))
    # random.sample make a random sample (without returns)
    # we use len(word) as length of the sample
    # so effectively obtain shuffled letters
    # new_letters is a list, so we have to use "".join
    print('E-G says : '+ "".join(new_letters))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `random.shuffle` on a conversion of the string in a list (works in-place)

Then convert back to string using `str.join`

```
import random

s =  "Happy"

sl = list(s)
random.shuffle(sl)

print("".join(sl))
```

outputs:

```
pyapH
Hpayp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print reversed word this would be fastest approach:

```
print(input("writte one word of your choice? : ")[::-1])
```

Comment: but OP doesn't want that.